# Rails 6, displaying images in CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I am trying to change my webpage background to an image using CSS.  I cannot figure out for the life of me how to reference once of my Rails 6 images in CSS though.  I've tried asset-url, image-url.  I've gotten the image to work using HTML with the following code.

```
<%= image_pack_tag 'Slide1.jpg' %>
```

How do I use my "image pack" images in CSS?

Comment: Where is your `Slide1.jpg` image in your app?

Comment: It's in app/javascript/images

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Chase!

Have you considered moving the image to the public asset pipeline?
If you move the Slide1.jpg to `/public/images/Slide1.jpg` then you can reference the image with ease:

`background_image: url('/images/Slide1.jpg')`.

Alternatively you can move it to the native pipeline (`app/assets/images`) and reference the asset URL in CSS.

Comment: I tried adding it to that first directory, and the url command caused my webpacker not to compile.  Using the pipeline way, what command do I use?  i tried image_url() but that wanted the picture in my stylesheets directory.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace that prevented webpacker from compiling?